# Trying to use reledmac with luatexja

Tags: miktex, reledmac, japanese, luatexja

I am using MikTeX 2.9, and trying to get the reledmac package working with luatexja. Both packages work fine if I try to use them on their own, but if I combine them I get the same error whether or not there's actually any Japanese text in the file.

If I have both packages included in a file that doesn't try to use the reledmac features, it works (e.g. just a begin document, "hi", and end document). Japanese text works fine as well.

Here is a minimal sample that attempts to use reledmac:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
hello world
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the \usepackage{luatexja} it works fine. But with that in there, I get the following error:

Section 1 (./untitled-2.1) (./untitled-2.eledsec1)error: ...a/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-jfmglue.lua:538: attempt to call field '?' (a nil value)
.

to be read again
\ltj@@reset@badness

l.9 \endnumbering

?

I would guess this to be some sort of encoding issue, but there's no actual Japanese text in the file.

Comment: I think it is a bug of reledmac. In order to let me do more investigation, please open an issue on github page.

Comment: but the better should be to send an email to both luatexja and me … because I have made some test and for now I can't see what are the modification made by luatexja which cause problem

Comment: I asked on the luatexja forum and they fixed it for me, so it is working now. https://osdn.jp/projects/luatex-ja/forums/25558/37917/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above, the author of luatexja fixed this for me; you can download the updated file from osdn.jp/projects/luatex-ja/forums/25558/37917 Hopefully it will be included in the next release.